# Second Commutator is Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(From I. Martin Isaacs: Algebra, A Graduate Course)

Let $G$ be any group. Prove that if $G''$ is cyclic, then $G'' \subseteq Z(G')$.

**Hint** (as presented in the book): consider $G/C_{G}(G'')$ and $Aut(G'')$.

Any ideas of how to use this hint?

Comment: Yes, the automorphism group of a cyclic group is abelian, so $G''$ must be centralized by $G'$ in the action of $G$ on $G''$ by conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $N \unlhd G$ then $G/C_G(N)$ can be isomorphically embedded in $Aut(N)$. Hence $G/C_G(G'') \hookrightarrow Aut(G'')$. But $G''$ is cyclic, implying $Aut(G'')$ is abelian. So $G/C_G(G'')$ is abelian, hence $G' \subseteq C_G(G'')$. This implies on its turn that $G'' \subseteq Z(G')$, and you are done.

**Note** [similar reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295786/if-g-g-and-g-g-are-cyclic-then-g-1) would prove that if $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are both cyclic, then $G''=G'''$.